# Change Embedded Browser on vSphere Client for a Web Based Plug-in

Tags: internet-explorer, plugins, vmware, ie8-compatibility-mode

I am developing a Web Based Plug-in for vSphere that is only compatible with Internet Explorer 8+. When I try to run it with the embedded Internet Explorer in vSphere Client, it does not work.

My system's Internet Explorer is the 8, but when I check the browser version with a script, it is always says version 7 with document mode 8.0. I still do not know if the embedded browser is an Internet Explorer 7 or an Internet Explorer with forced Compatibility View.

I already used user agents such as `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EDGE" >` to make sure to disable the Compatibilty View on IE. Besides that, I already disabled the Compatibility View in the IE options.

### Question

Is it possible to set the browser embedded by VMware, update the Internet Explorer or prevent it to use Compatibility Mode?